# Not able to send any POST request from Clerk to Vercel

Tags: typescript, next.js, webhooks, vercel, clerk

I am trying to add webhook to my project for the Clerk

**app\api\webhooks\route.ts**

```
import { Webhook } from "svix";
import { headers } from "next/headers";
import { WebhookEvent } from "@clerk/nextjs/server";
import { createUser, deleteUser, updateUser } from "@/lib/actions/user.action";
import { NextResponse } from "next/server";

export async function POST(req: Request) {
  // You can find this in the Clerk Dashboard -> Webhooks -> choose the webhook
  const WEBHOOK_SECRET = process.env.NEXT_CLERK_WEBHOOK_SECRET;

  if (!WEBHOOK_SECRET) {
    throw new Error(
      "Please add WEBHOOK_SECRET from Clerk Dashboard to .env or .env.local"
    );
  }

  // Get the headers
  const headerPayload = headers();
  const svix_id = headerPayload.get("svix-id");
  const svix_timestamp = headerPayload.get("svix-timestamp");
  const svix_signature = headerPayload.get("svix-signature");

  // If there are no headers, error out
  if (!svix_id || !svix_timestamp || !svix_signature) {
    return new Response("Error occured -- no svix headers", {
      status: 400,
    });
  }

  // Get the body
  const payload = await req.json();
  const body = JSON.stringify(payload);

  // Create a new Svix instance with your secret.
  const wh = new Webhook(WEBHOOK_SECRET);

  let evt: WebhookEvent;

  // Verify the payload with the headers
  try {
    evt = wh.verify(body, {
      "svix-id": svix_id,
      "svix-timestamp": svix_timestamp,
      "svix-signature": svix_signature,
    }) as WebhookEvent;
  } catch (err) {
    console.error("Error verifying webhook:", err);
    return new Response("Error occured", {
      status: 400,
    });
  }

  const eventType = evt.type; 

  console.log({ eventType });
  console.log("hi");

  if (eventType === "user.created") {
    const { id, email_addresses, image_url, username, first_name, last_name } =
      evt.data;

    

    // Create a new user in your database
    const mongoUser = await createUser({
      clerkId: id,
      fullName: `${first_name}${last_name ? `${last_name}` : ""}`,
      username: username!,
      email: email_addresses[0].email_address,
      profilePicture: image_url,
    });
    return NextResponse.json({ message: "OK", user: mongoUser });
  }
  if (eventType === "user.updated") {
    //agar user mai kuch update hota hai tab mujhe
    const { id, email_addresses, image_url, username, first_name, last_name } =
      evt.data;
    const mongoUser = await updateUser({
      clerkId: id,
      updateData: {
        fullName: `${first_name}${last_name ? `${last_name}` : ""}`,
        username: username!,
        email: email_addresses[0].email_address,
        profilePicture: image_url,
      },
      path: `/profile/${id}`,
    });
    return NextResponse.json({ message: "OK", user: mongoUser });
  }

  if (eventType === "user.deleted") {
    const { id } = evt.data;
    const deletedUser = await deleteUser({
      clerkId: id!,
    });
    return NextResponse.json({ message: "OK", user: deletedUser });
  }

  return new Response("", { status: 201 });
}
```

**middleware.ts**

```
 import { authMiddleware } from "@clerk/nextjs";
    
    export default authMiddleware({
      publicRoutes: [
        "/",
        "/api/webhooks(.*)",
        "question/:id",
        "/tags",
        "tags/:id",
        "/profile/:id",
        "/community",
        "/jobs",
      ],
      ignoredRoutes: ["/api/webhook", "/api/chatgpt"],
    });
    
    export const config = {
      matcher: ["/((?!.+\\.[\\w]+$|_next).*)", "/", "/(api|trpc)(.*)"],
    };
```

After this I added the endpoint url to the clerk webhook
[Image of Clerk Webhook Endpoint Url](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IKWC3.png)

But when I am checking my log of my deployed project I am not able to see any request related to the /api/webhook by Clerk
[Screenshot of Vercel Deployed project>logs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U6nh2.png)

Please help me solving this issue!

I rechecked all my code and not able to figure out the problem

Comment: Don't you get the cause for the failure in the Clerk dashboard?

Comment: @grekier no buddy, I am just seeing failed error as show in the webhook image I have attached previously

Comment: That's sad and a good reason for me not to try Clerk ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved this problem by disable the authentication in project settings
For more details check this article:
https://vercel.com/docs/security/deployment-protection/methods-to-protect-deployments/vercel-authentication#managing-vercel-authentication